# How to exclude trailing slash on source URL when redirecting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have to make a 301 redirect from a domain to another (`example-a.com` to `example-b.com`).

This is the code I put in `.htaccess` of `example-a.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example-b.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

All URLs are the same, except pages of `example-a.com` all have a `/` (slash) at the end of the URL, but `example-b.com` does not. So how to redirect without the ending `/` if the URL contains one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example-b.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

To exclude the slash from the redirected URL, then exclude the slash from the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. eg. `^(.*)/$`.

However, assuming you also want the document root to redirect, where there is no slash in the URL-path, then you need to make the trailing slash optional (or create an entirely separate rule). But in that case you need to also make the capturing group *non-greedy*, otherwise the trailing slash will always be included in the captured group (since regex is *greedy* by default).

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://www.example-b.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Since the earlier 301s will have likely been cached.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that it works OK. This is to avoid the browser caching erroneous redirects whilst testing.